# Server Response 414 Request-URI Too Long on method PUT

Tags: php, apache, laravel, put

Im using the method PUT to create a new client on my API, but one the fields are the base64 image and he is too large. The response of the server is

> 414 Request-URI Too Long - The requested URL's length exceeds the
>   capacity limit for this server.

I tried to change the configs LimitRequestLine and LimitRequestFieldSize, I set 500000 but the error continue.

I try method POST and everything is ok!

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet of how you do the put request? In general you should not transfer base64 encoded images in the url. It should always be in the request body. The body is not limited to that size.

Comment: Thank you! I found the error, I was sending the values on the request parameters and not on the body, I changed and requests returns success!